# How can I prevent users with javascript disabled from submiting a form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

We have an inquiry form where users are required with JS to at least enter their name, location, contact information, comment/question, etc. We've been getting A LOT of completely blank and semi-blank forms. We know that if the user has JS disabled, they can click the submit button with nothing filled in. I've looked into the possibility of disabling the submit button unless JS is enabled, but I've read that a lot of people think this is a bad idea. Suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Don't create a submit button but submit with a Javascript function.

Comment: also do your validation server side, and reject any submission that don't have the required info.

Comment: This is why you should *always* validate on the server.  *Never* trust user input.  Have your PHP validate it, and if it's bad, then throw away the data.  Why should I be forced to have JS enabled?  Also, what if I decide to send you fake data from cURL or something and not a web browser?

Comment: This is an aside; but what sort of mug disables javascript these days? I can't imagine many sites other than the MOST basic would function without JS

Comment: An hacker i think @daveL

Comment: @daveL: I know people who use NoScript.  They'll only enable JS for a site if they need to.

Comment: @RocketHazmat but that can disable on a site by site basis right?

Comment: can you tell whether these "empty forms" are submitted by crawlers or by humans? Probably these are the usual crawlers running around and submitting almost everything not protected by captchas?

Comment: @daveL: Yeah, but it's "disabled" by default unless you enable the site.

Comment: @daveL We are pretty sure it's people trying to hack. Most of the semi-blank forms have random letters for the name (i.e. "ibkdfwjle") and "Google" for the company. I'm pretty positive no one named ibkdfwjli from Google is trying to ask a legitimate question! ;)

Comment: @AxelAmthor Our next step is adding a captcha. We can't tell if the forms are from real people or crawlers. Maybe a mixture of both? I suppose adding a captcha would be the easiest way to tell.

Comment: @HHArtmann Adding a captcha is always an ultima ratio since it decreases conversion and usability. Check your logs, investigate on the IP addresses from where the "submitters" are coming. Most crawlers are coming from russia, eastern europe, india or china. Have a look at the user agent strings and probably the referrers for "unusual" stuff. If you're sure, that you are suffering from crawlers, then add a captcha. Otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent a blank form from being submitted by various techniques.  Your server should be validating the form and rejecting submissions that are not proper.  This is a core fundamental of any server that accepts data from any outside source.  It must do its own data validation before accepting the data.

It is possible to make a form such that the browser can't submit it to your site via a plain browser without javascript being enabled.  For example, if there's no default action for the form in the HTML and the submit action is only implemented in javascript, then the form wouldn't submit if javascript was disabled.  There would still be other ways to submit the data without client-side verification which is why server-side validation is always required, but this might stop some user mistakes before they get to your server.

You can also use the `<noscript>` tag to advise the user that javascript is required.

---

You can identify many form submissions from robots server-side immediately by just including a form in your field that is populated with a known value via javascript.  If, when the form is received on your server, that known value is not present in the form, then the form is likely submitted by something other than a browser with javascript enabled.

You can prevent automatic robot submissions by just not using a regular form action in your HTML.  If the submission URL is only in your javascript and the submissions is only done via javascript, then most robots will never see it and never even know to try (because they don't run javascript).

FYI, neither of these last two techniques will prevent hackers from submitting rogue forms/data since they may analyze things enough to understand what is missing, but they can help identify automated attempts at submissions.

Answer (score 0):

On your server side, thais `php` `trim` the data before putting in database or any other operation. Trim removes the empty spaces away.. Also check for `sql injections`

[See here for trim](https://www.php.net/trim)

[SQL Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

First, use the noscript tag to tell users they need javascript when they load the form.

Second, since form submission can't always completely prevented have the HTML form submit to a page which does not process the submission but instead tells them they must have javascript.  To handle correct submissions on your form page use javascript to change the form submit action to the correct submit page.